# (Recasting data as cross reference table in R) Extracting variable (Z) dimensioned on two categorical variables (X & Y)

Tags: r

This seems like it should be simple, but I have been struggling for a while to solve. I am trying to extract the value of variable Z - given the values of two categorical variables X & Y.

** BUT, I want to do this for all combinations of X & Y **

So, for any given value, this is easy - I can get Z by using the following code (Assume the data frame is called df):

```
df[df$X == 1 & df$Y == 2, ]$Z
```

**But, I would like to use this to build a cross-reference table.**

The following example will make this easy to understand.

*Here's a simplified version of the data frame as it comes in:*

```
Person ID    Question Number    Response
   1            10                 YES
   1            20                 NO
   1            30                 YES
   2            10                 YES
   2            20                 MAYBE
   2            30                 YES
   3            10                 YES
   3            30                 NO
   4            20                 NO 
   4            30                 MAYBE
```

I want to be able to take this data and make a cross-reference data.frame, like so:

*[row names are the levels of "Person ID" and col names are the levels of "Question Number"]*

```
     [10]     [20]     [30]
[1]   YES      NO      YES  
[2]   YES     MAYBE    YES  
[3]   YES      N/A     NO    
[4]   N/A      NO      MAYBE
```

I have tried the "table" function gives me summary statistics, frequency counts. So, if I use the following:

```
table(df$Person.Id, df$Question.Num)
```

I get the right row and column headings, but the values are frequency counts. Since this is a cross-reference table, I need that to be the value for df$Response instead of the frequency count.

As I said before, I can manually find every value of df$Response using the following code

```
df[df$Person.ID == "1" & df$Question.Num == "20", ]$Response
```

But, I cannot manage to stitch this together into a data.frame. I tried to use nested for loops, but couldnt get it to work. I could get all the value out, but no way to stitch everything into a cross-reference table, as described above.

*Just a background note: this is a necessary preparatory step so I can minimize logit linear model.*

Comment: You can use `reshape` to convert the date to wide format.

Comment: Try `library(tidyr);spread(df, Question.Num, Response)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by Metrics, I did the following:

```
install.packages("reshape")
library("reshape")

cast(df, Person.Id~Question.Num, value = "Response")
```

That last part is key. The value = "Response" tells the cast function what variable to use to fill in the table.

This is a fantastic package. You can find more information on it here:

http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html

and, the original paper published in the *Journal of Statistical Software*:

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper

Thanks for the tips!

I never tried the tidyr package, because the reshape package worked so well. Perhaps, it is just as easy with that package. I leave it to the community to figure that out.

Thanks!